# Does CouchBase (2.0.1) supports windows 32 bits?

Tags: couchbase

The [download](http://www.couchbase.com/download) page does not have a Windows build for the most recent version - 2.0.1. There is a windows 64 bits installation for the version 2.0.0.

I was wondering about the reasons of not supporting Windows 32 bits since 2.0.0 and Windows at all since 2.0.1.

Is it that they do not provide the binaries, but one could still build it for Windows 32 bits using [the build instructions](http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Building+Couchbase+from+Source+on+Windows) ?

Or there is a deeper reason, like using an API unavailable for Windows 32 bits (2.0.0) or unavailable for Windows at all (2.0.1) ?

I am asking because I am considering building it on Windows, both 32 and 64 bits, but would like to be sure the effort is not doomed to failure from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are well aware of the situation. The plan is to release 2.0.1 for 64 bits as soon as possible. We're having some delays for our Windows builds and want to make sure the quality is as high as possible. So expect a 2.0.1 64bit soon.

That said, I don't think that we'll have production ready versions of 2.0.x 32bit. What we are currently working on is a 32bit build that people can use to develop against, but is not recommended to use in production (similar to our Mac OS X builds).

I can't give you a specific timeline, but I think we're talking about "weeks". If you want to get direct feedback from one of the developers, please get in touch with Trond Norbye over twitter (@trondn).

Does this answer your question?